# Please help me understand this trend code

Tags: pine-script

```
up = atrSource - atrMultiplier * atr
upNz = nz(up[1], up)
upMax = math.max(up, upNz)
up := close[1] > upNz ? upMax : up

dn = atrSource + atrMultiplier * atr
dnNz = nz(dn[1], dn)
dnMin = math.min(dn, dnNz)
dn := close[1] < dnNz ? dnMin : dn

trend = 1
trend := nz(trend[1], trend)
trend := trend == -1 and close > dnNz ? 1 : trend == 1 and close < upNz ? -1 : trend

buySignal = trend == 1 and trend[1] == -1
sellSignal = trend == -1 and trend[1] == 1
```

I'm new to pine-script.  I'm trying to understand this code above.  It's part of an indicator showing a Supertrend.

trend = 1

We're creating a new variable called trend and assigning it a value of 1.

trend := nz(trend[1], trend)

Now we're using the built-in function nz to make the second value of trend with 1.
trend was a variable and now it's an array?

trend := trend == -1 and close > dnNz ? 1 : trend == 1 and close < upNz ? -1 : trend

The above line it a little complicated, but my main question is, isn't trend always 1?  We assigned it 1 just two lines up.  Why are we checking if it is -1?

I appreciate all replies!

I want to understand this trend code, so I tried to simplify that long conditional line.
It didn't work.  The supertrend line changed.  I don't want to change it.  I just want to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

> Now we're using the built-in function nz to make the second value of
> trend with 1. trend was a variable and now it's an array?

No, it is not an array. `nz()` returns a `simple int`.

```
nz(source, replacement) → simple int
```

> The above line it a little complicated, but my main question is, isn't
> trend always 1? We assigned it 1 just two lines up. Why are we
> checking if it is -1?

You can write that same expression as:

```
trend := if ((trend == -1) and (close > dnNz))
    1
else
    if ((trend == 1) and (close < upNz))
        -1
    else
        trend
```

To answer your question: No, it is not always 1. `nz()` will only kick in if the `source` is `NaN`. Otherwise, it will return the value of the `source`.

So, when `trend[1] = 1` and you pass that to `nz()`, it will simply return the value of `trend[1]` which is 1 in this example. Because it is not `na`.